# Remove columns from WooCommerce admin coupon list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, coupon

I am trying to remove some default columns (amount & products) from the WooCommerce admin coupon list.

For that I make use of the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'custom_post_columns', 10, 2 );
function custom_post_columns( $columns, $post_type ) {
  
    switch ( $post_type ) {    
    
    case 'shop_coupon':
        unset(
            $columns['amount'],
            $columns['products']
        );
        break;
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

---

But it doesn't work and I'm not getting any errors. I think the code I'm using is just not being applied correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `manage_edit-{post type or taxonomy}_columns` filter hook

So you get:

```php
function filter_manage_edit_shop_coupon_columns( $columns ) {
    // Remove
    unset( $columns['products'] );
    unset( $columns['amount'] );    

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_coupon_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_coupon_columns', 10, 1 );
```